# Active Record Query 'where' to ignore spaces

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How do I get all the records from db that match given string without spaces?

For example:

db record: `"Hello beautiful world!"`

given string: `name = "Hello  beau tifulworld !"`

Is it possible to make it as Active Record Query?

Comment: This isn't really an ActiveRecord issue, I don't think. You'll likely have to find a solution to this in SQL using whatever regex support your specific database provides and then pass in a line of raw sql to the Active Record Query. oh, and not my downvote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can search by name without spaces. Something like this (for postgres):

```
Model.where("replace(name, ' ', '') = replace(?, ' ', '')", 'Hello  beau tifulworld !')
```

Comment: Thanks, actually I proceed as: ```name = "Hello  beau tifulworld !" Model.where("replace(name, ' ', '') = replace(?, ' ', '')", "#{name}")```

Answer (score 0):

What comes to my mind is that you can search the records by sorted names from both sides. 
I mean, first in a new created array with the names and ids of the records you sort the record names, by something like

`record.name.chars.sort.join` and you also sort your 
`matching_word = "Hello beautiful world!"`

to get `!Habdeefilllloortuuw"`

Then you can get the ids of the records that match this helper name.
In next step you can get these records from the database.

Good luck!